# NSTimer is not firing from Singleton Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, nstimer

I have a singleton class that I want to run in the background and check for photos to upload. The singleton is initialized from another viewcontroller via

```
[[EXOImageUploader sharedPhotoUploader] startPhotoUploadCheck];
```

If I NSLog everything, it appears the singleton is working. I can do other things in the singleton that aren't shown below just fine. The `NSTimer` just never fires. I have even commented out the line that checks to see if the timer `isValid` but that doesn't work either.

***Any idea on why my Timer is working?***

**Here is the order that the NSLog's spit out.**

1. sharedPhotoUploader init
2. doSetup
3. Timer interval: 1.000000
4. sharedPhotoUploader singleton
5. startPhotoUploadCheck

***Here is the code.***

**.h**

```
@interface EXOImageUploader : NSObject
@property (assign) NSTimeInterval timerCheckInterval;

+ (EXOImageUploader *) sharedPhotoUploader;

- (void) startPhotoUploadCheck;
- (void) stopPhotoUploadCheck;
```

**.m**

```
@interface EXOImageUploader ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer* timerUpload;
@end

@implementation EXOImageUploader 

static EXOImageUploader* _sharedPhotoUploader;

#pragma mark - SINGLETON SETUP

+ (EXOImageUploader *) sharedPhotoUploader {

    static EXOImageUploader *sharedPhotoUploader = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedPhotoUploader = [[self alloc] init];
         NSLog(@"sharedPhotoUploader singleton");
    });
    return sharedPhotoUploader;

}

- (id) init {
    if (self =  [super init]){
         NSLog(@"sharedPhotoUploader init");
        [self doSetup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) doSetup {
     NSLog(@"doSetup");
    if (!self.timerCheckInterval) {
        self.timerCheckInterval = 1.0f;
    }
    NSLog(@"Timer interval: %f", self.timerCheckInterval);

}

#pragma mark Public Methods

- (void) startPhotoUploadCheck {
    NSLog(@"startPhotoUploadCheck");
    //Don't start a new one if this one is running
     if (!_timerUpload) {
    _timerUpload = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:_timerCheckInterval target:self selector:@selector(checkForPhotosToUpload) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

}

- (void) stopPhotoUploadCheck {
     NSLog(@"stopPhotoUploadCheck");
    [_timerUpload invalidate];
    _timerUpload = nil;
}
```

Comment: If timerUpload is nil, it doesnt go through the if block , so your timer will always stay nil. Did u try to declare the timer as a property?

Comment: I did. Please see revised question.

Comment: Try giving float instead of NSTimeInterval.

Comment: Tried that and it did not work.

Comment: The timer must be scheduled in order to fire.  Either schedule it after creation, or use scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval.

Comment: Is calling `startPhotoUploadCheck` not creating the timer? @danh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` instead of `timerWithTimeInterval`.

The docs for `timerWithTimeInterval` say: "You must add the new timer to a run loop, using addTimer:forMode:".

With the "scheduled" version, that's already done for you.

Comment: AH! Perfect! that was the ticket!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use your timer without initializing it, thus it will be nil and won't fire. Activate your timer like this:

```
[timerUpload scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];
```

Comment: You don't need the alloc/init.  `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` is a class method that returns a new instance.